# Bootstrap 4/5 Different navbar-brand css when navbar is in mobile size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5 and have a navbar which shows the navbar-toggler-icon when in mobile size.
My issue is that I need to change the css of the position of the logo when it's in mobile size.

So:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
```

The above would have different css when in mobile size.

Here is the nav code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="./images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 w-100">
            <li class="nav-item flex-fill">
              <a
                class="nav-link active"
                aria-current="page"
                href="#"
                >Column 1</a
              >
            </li>
            
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

I have this css:

```
.navbar .navbar-brand img {
  position: relative;
  top: -26px;
  width: 46px;
  height: 52px;
}
```

which I only want to use when the size is NOT mobile

How can I do that?

Comment: Try `container-fluid` as a wrapper for your outer `nav`, not the inner.

Comment: @Devart - The issue is that I have this css: .navbar .navbar-brand img {
  position: relative;
  top: -26px;
  width: 46px;
  height: 52px;
} ... which I only want to use when the size is NOT mobile

Comment: Check my answer below. Use `media-queries` to use that style only from the `min-width` you want. So it won't be used under that width. PS : Add the css tag to your question. And use the `StackOverflow HTML/CSS/JS snippet` function in question editor to add your code with a preview of it, so we can test/run it like a JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your CSS after `xs` breakpoint, use `media-queries` with bootstrap breakpoints. [Here is the doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#min-width).

### Via Sass

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) { 
    .navbar .navbar-brand img {
        position: relative;
        top: -26px;
        width: 46px;
        height: 52px;
    }
}
```

And I suggest you to [use bootstrap via Sass](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/), so you could use their functions, mixins, and some extended css rules :)

If you don't want to use Sass, create a media querie with `min-width: 576px`. In fact `576px` corresponds to the **`xs` breakpoint**.

### Via CSS

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .navbar .navbar-brand img {
        position: relative;
        top: -26px;
        width: 46px;
        height: 52px;
    }
}
```